# How to specify a PHP version when using "php" command

Tags: php

I have a server which have both PHP 5.2 and 5.3 on it, default version is 5.2 and whenever i uses  command "php" it takes the 5.2 version. Is there any way i can specify the version while running command? php -v  only display the version.

For application i use .htaccess  to set version, like `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53 .php`

Is there any similar way while using command "php"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/usr/bin/php5.3` but using your path to the correct php version. You can use `which php` to find the path.

If you don't want to type the full path, you can setup an alias in your .bashrc